# Android for loop List

Tags: android, database, list, calendar

I have a list that is populated with data taken from database.
The data of the list are passed to the view to display them. For each id taken from the database, I want to add a day to the calendar, then, I added the id what I need in an array, in order to have them sorted.
The problem is the loop in the list, instead of iterating based on the number of id in the array, the cycle continues without stopping ... I hope I explained, this is all the code

```
private Integer[] id_nome_op;
public void checkOperatori() { 
    SQLiteDatabase db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()).getReadableDatabase();
    String OPERATORI = "SELECT _id, ...... ORDER BY _id ASC";
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(OPERATORI, null);
    int count = cur.getCount();
    id_nome_op = new Integer[count];
    nome_op = new String[count];
    cognome_op = new String[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cur.moveToNext();
        id_nome_op[i] = cur.getInt(0);
        nome_op[i] = cur.getString(1);
        cognome_op[i] = cur.getString(2);

        mWeekView.setData(nome_op, cognome_op);
    }
    cur.close();
    db.close();

}


@Override
public List<WeekViewEvent>onMonthChange(int newYear, int newMonth) {
       SimpleDateFormat simpleFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
       final String strDate = simpleFormat.format(calendarioFooter.getTime());

       List<WeekViewEvent> events = new ArrayList<WeekViewEvent>();
       SQLiteDatabase db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()).getReadableDatabase();
       String tabella_op = "SELECT m._id, m.id_operatore, ...........";
       Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(tabella_op, null);
 while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        startTime = (Calendar) calendarioFooter.clone();
        id_appuntamento = cur.getString(0);
        id_operator = cur.getInt(1);
        dat = cur.getString(2);
        ora_iniz = cur.getString(3);
        ora_fin = cur.getString(4);
        id_servizio = cur.getString(5);
        id_client = cur.getString(6);
        nome_cliente = cur.getString(7);
        cognome_cliente = cur.getString(8);
        nome_operatore = cur.getString(9);
        colore_serv = cur.getInt(10);
        tipo_serv = cur.getString(11);

 int giorno_ok = Integer.parseInt(dat.substring(8, 10));
 int ora_inizio = Integer.parseInt(ora_iniz.substring(0, 2));
 int minuto_inizio = Integer.parseInt(ora_iniz.substring(3, 5));
 int ora_fine = Integer.parseInt(ora_fin.substring(0, 2));
 int minuto_fine = Integer.parseInt(ora_fin.substring(3, 5));


int size = id_nome_op.length;//array id
for(int i = 1; i< size; i++){

        if (i == 1) {

            startTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, giorno_ok);


        } else if (i == 2) {

            startTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, giorno_ok);
            startTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

        } else if (i == 3) {

            startTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, giorno_ok);
            startTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);

        }

        startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, ora_inizio);
        startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuto_inizio);
        startTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, newMonth - 1);
        startTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, newYear);

        Calendar endTime = (Calendar) startTime.clone();
        endTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, ora_fine);
        endTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuto_fine);

WeekViewEvent event = new WeekViewEvent(id_appuntamento, getEventTitle(startTime), startTime, endTime);
        event.setColor(colore_serv);
        events.add(event);
        }
    }
    cur.close();
    db.close();
    return events;
}
```

Comment: where did you set `id_nome_op`

Comment: Maybe your function `onMonthChange` runs several times?? try to block running at the same time. Because, you are adding to calendar, so maybe when event date is in next month, it takes affect. Try to block parallel runs, and you'll solve your problem. I think